# Проблема Inline Button Telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Я разрабатываю телеграмм бота с помощью модуля telebot и для моего бота нужны Inline кнопки читая документацию научился создавать 2 типа Inline и Reply и создал сценарий

Ошибка лежит именно в создании следующей функции моего сценария где ещё раз используется InlineKeyboardButton изменив переменную markup7 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton я думал что функция будет работать но нет происходит ошибка

```
# Ошибка
2021-04-07 20:54:23,638 (__init__.py:515 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API 
was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty"
```

### Код Python

> Первая функция (Keybord)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['command'])
def start_messages(message):
   markup9 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True, )
   markup9.add('Кнопка', 'Кнопка1') 

   markup = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
   markup.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка', callback_data='Кнопка'))

   m = bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBBcJgWKQRpsEbVy0IOtCDeylcbm8JrAACfwADO2AkFCFdm7Q_uejcHgQ',
                     reply_markup=markup9)
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Choose the genre API ", reply_markup=markup, )
   bot.register_next_step_handler(m, process_step9)

def process_step9(message):
   chat_id = message.chat.id
   if message.text == 'Кнопка':
    start_messages(message)
   elif message.text == 'Кнопка1':
    help_message(message)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
   def query_handler(call):
      bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='Текст')
      answer = ''
     if call.data == 'Кнопка':
        answer = (random.choice(list0) + "Текст")  # Список в полном коде есть
     bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, answer)
```

> Вторая функция (Keybord)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['command1'])
  def start_messages1(message):
     markup8 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True, )
     markup8.add('Кнопка', 'Кнопка') 

     markup7 = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
     markup7.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка', callback_data='Кнопка3'))
     markup7.add(telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Кнопка', callback_data='Кнопка4'))

     bm = bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBBcJgWKQRpsEbVy0IOtCDeylcbm8JrAACfwADO2AkFCFdm7Q_uejcHgQ',
                      reply_markup=markup7)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Текст', reply_markup=markup8)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(bm, process_step7)

def process_step7(message):
   chat_id = message.chat.id
   if message.text == 'Кнопка':
    start_messages(message)
   elif message.text == 'Кнопка':
    help_message(message)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call1: True)
   def query_handler1(call):
      bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, text='Спасибо за выбор!')

      answer = ''
      if call.data == 'Кнопка3':
        answer0 = "Test"  
      elif call.data == 'Кнопка4':
        answer = "Test"  

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, answer)
```

Увидели уже мои ошибки прошу вас указать на них чтобы без проблем написать код второй функции буду очень благодарен за помощь !

Comment: Возможно ему не нравится `text=None`.

Comment: Изменил ошибка осталась